# How Fix this error java/lang/Object.class) : major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

[This error display when deploy soluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xBxv.jpg)

[This message display when start virtualbox and every once start virtual say problem in device and restart it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYBpY.jpg)

Comment: Change network settings: try connecting in bridge.

Comment: I changed but still problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your JDK, and try to change it for 'latest' at -> Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options ->Xamarin -> Android Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when first upgrading to Android SDK build tools v24 if you are not targeting JDK 8. For notes and various workarounds see: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/

I have pasted some workarounds from the above link for your convenience:

1. Update to Java JDK 8, and then make sure that JDK 8 is selected in the Xamarin preferences:
   Visual Studio: Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Java Development Kit Location.
   Xamarin Studio (on Mac): Xamarin Studio > Preferences > Projects > SDK Locations > Android > Java SDK (JDK).
2. Uninstall all Android SDK Build-tools versions 24 and higher via the Android SDK manager.
3. Set the AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion MSBuild property to an earlier version. For example, if you also have version 23.0.3 installed, you could add the following line within the top `<PropertyGroup>` element in the Android project .csproj file:
   `<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>`